# Validate COMPLETE XML Against XSD

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I want to validate my XML against my XSD **COMPLETELY**, meaning that I want the file to continue validating from the same point where it had thrown an exception.

This is my code :

```
public void validate(File file) {
    try {

        Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(file);

        try {

            System.out.println("Processing : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(validator);
            validator.validate(xmlFile);
            // stringBuffer.append(" is valid");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            fileWriter.write("\n\n\n" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
            System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            fileWriter.write("\nReason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            if (e instanceof SAXParseException) {
                fileWriter.write(" (Line : "
                        + ((SAXParseException) e).getLineNumber()
                        + ", Col : "
                        + ((SAXParseException) e).getColumnNumber() + ")");
            }

            fileWriter.flush();
            validate(file);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Here according to this snippet, after JUST ONE EXCEPTION the code returns the error and stops validating further XML.. But is there any way to get all the errors of the XML against the XSD? In short to continue validating from the cursor where it had thrown an exception.
ANY WAY OUT??

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to validate XML against an XSL file. You can validate against a schema (XML Schema, DTD, RelaxNG, etc.), but not against a stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the default error handler is to stop processing after the first fatal error is encountered by throwing a `SAXException`. To alter this behavior, implement your own [`ErrorHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) and register it with your validator.

This is an example that just dumps the exceptions to standard output, but you would probably want to replace it with a more intelligent reporting mechanism.

```
class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    public void error( SAXParseException e ) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    public void warning( SAXParseException e ) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

And then:

```
validator.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
```